# Constant Width SashForm

Tags: java, swt

My application has a SashForm with two children. I want the left child to stay the same size when the window is resized. I want the same thing Eclipse does with the Package Explorer and the main editor. When you resize the window only the text editor changes size. However, the Package Explorer is still resizeable by the sash.

I tried using the following

```
sashForm.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
        int width = sashForm.getClientArea().width;
        int[] weights = sashForm.getWeights();
        weights[1] = width - weights[0];
        sashForm.setWeights(weights);
    }
});
```

The problem is the width of the left size either shrinks to 0 or expands too much. It looks like the weights are updated before this is called or something.

If I set weights[0] equal to some constant it does what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best solution I could come up with.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.SashForm;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class Main {
private static int leftWidth, oldWeight;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setSize(600, 400);

    final SashForm form = new SashForm(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);

    final Button button = new Button(form, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Left");

    button.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            int[] weights = form.getWeights();
            // oldWeights is used to distinguish between a window resize and
            // a sash move
            if (oldWeight != weights[0]) {
                System.out.println("Weights changed!");
                oldWeight = weights[0];
                leftWidth = (int) Math.round((double) form.getClientArea().width
                        * (double) weights[0]
                        / (double) (weights[0] + weights[1]));
            }
        }
    });

    Button buttonR = new Button(form, SWT.PUSH);
    buttonR.setText("Right");

    form.setWeights(new int[] { 200, 800 });
    leftWidth = 200;

    form.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
            int width = form.getClientArea().width;
            int[] weights = form.getWeights();

            double perChange = (double) leftWidth / (double) width;

            weights[0] = (int) (perChange * 1000.0);
            weights[1] = 1000 - weights[0];

            // oldWeights must be set before form.setWeights
            oldWeight = weights[0];
            form.setWeights(weights);
        }
    });

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

The sash jumps around about 1px when the window is resized due to rounding issues, but it seems to do what I want.

This is a very hacky solution and I would like to know if there is a better one. It also crashes if you make the window smaller than the left button, but that is easy to fix.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get an example running that should give you an idea how to solve your problem. The thing is, that the `SashForm` uses weights rather than pixels. So you have to compute the percentage the left child has to occupy based on the parent size and assign the rest to the right child.

In my code example, you can specify the width of the left child and set a minimal size for the right child, such that the `SashForm` will always show both.

```
private static final int MIN_WIDTH_LEFT = 100;
private static final int MIN_WIDTH_RIGHT = 50;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final SashForm form = new SashForm(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);

    Button button = new Button(form, SWT.PUSH);
    button.setText("Left");

    Button buttonR = new Button(form, SWT.PUSH);
    buttonR.setText("Right");

    form.setWeights(new int[] {1, 2});

    shell.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event arg0)
        {
            int width = shell.getClientArea().width;
            int[] weights = form.getWeights();

            if(width >= MIN_WIDTH_LEFT + MIN_WIDTH_RIGHT)
            {
                weights[0] = 1000000 * MIN_WIDTH_LEFT / width;
                weights[1] = 1000000 - weights[0];
            }
            else
            {
                weights[0] = 1000000 * MIN_WIDTH_LEFT / (MIN_WIDTH_LEFT + MIN_WIDTH_RIGHT);
                weights[1] = 1000000 * MIN_WIDTH_RIGHT / (MIN_WIDTH_LEFT + MIN_WIDTH_RIGHT);
            }

            System.out.println(width + " " + Arrays.toString(weights));

            form.setWeights(weights);
        }
    });

    shell.pack();

    shell.setSize(600, 400);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

This is what it looks like:

Startup:

[image]

After resizing:

[image]

When decreasing the window size until it is too small to show both minimal sizes:

[image]

As you can see in this case, the minimal size for the left child is ignored to still be able to show both childs.

Comment: This roughly does what I want, but if you manually resize "Left" to be bigger than the preset width and you resize the window it jumps back to the preset width. I want the user set width to stay constant. In other words I need MIN_WIDTH_LEFT to be adjusted when the sash is manually moved.

Comment: @EmbMicro Well, nobody keeps you from doing that ;) Just remove the `final` keyword from the `MIN_WIDTH_LEFT` field and change its value.

Comment: It doesn't work though. I tried adding a listener to "Left" when it's resized and it gets smaller when the window is moved around.
`button.addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {
 @Override
 public void handleEvent(Event arg0) {
  MIN_WIDTH_LEFT = button.getBounds().width;
 }
});`

Comment: @EmbMicro Interestingly, there is no `Listener` that is fired when you move the `SashForm`... I tried a couple of things, but could not get it to fire at the appropriate time.

Answer (score 0):

Have to rewrite SashForm to get this behavior.  `new SashForm(Composite parent, int style)` is old behavior; `new SashForm(Composite parent, int style, false)` uses widths/heights specified in pixels.

Not tested with more than two Composite children of the SashForm, and odd behavior if you don't `setLength` when using new behavior, but will not break existing uses of SashForm

e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
Display display = new Display();
final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
shell.setText("StackOverflow");
shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
final SashForm form = new SashForm(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
Button button = new Button(form, SWT.PUSH);
button.setText("Left");
Button buttonR = new Button(form, SWT.PUSH);
buttonR.setText("Right");
form.setLengths(new int[] { 250, 25 });
shell.pack();
shell.setSize(600, 400);
shell.open();
while (!shell.isDisposed())
{
    if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
}
```

First button will default to 250 pixels, second the remainder shell

SashForm.java:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.*;

public class SashForm extends Composite {

    /**
    * The width of all sashes in the form.
    */
    public int SASH_WIDTH = 3;

    int sashStyle;
    final private boolean weighted;
    Sash[] sashes = new Sash[0];
    // Remember background and foreground
    // colors to determine whether to set
    // sashes to the default color (null) or
    // a specific color
    Color background = null;
    Color foreground = null;
    Control[] controls = new Control[0];
    Control maxControl = null;
    Listener sashListener;
    static final int DRAG_MINIMUM = 20;

public SashForm(Composite parent, int style) {
    super(parent, checkStyle(style));
    super.setLayout(new SashFormLayout());
    sashStyle = ((style & SWT.VERTICAL) != 0) ? SWT.HORIZONTAL : SWT.VERTICAL;
    if ((style & SWT.BORDER) != 0) sashStyle |= SWT.BORDER;
    if ((style & SWT.SMOOTH) != 0) sashStyle |= SWT.SMOOTH;
    sashListener = new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            onDragSash(e);
        }
    };
    weighted = true;
}
public SashForm(Composite parent, int style, boolean weighted) {
    super(parent, checkStyle(style));
    super.setLayout(new SashFormLayout());
    sashStyle = ((style & SWT.VERTICAL) != 0) ? SWT.HORIZONTAL : SWT.VERTICAL;
    if ((style & SWT.BORDER) != 0) sashStyle |= SWT.BORDER;
    if ((style & SWT.SMOOTH) != 0) sashStyle |= SWT.SMOOTH;
    sashListener = new Listener() {
        public void handleEvent(Event e) {
            onDragSash(e);
        }
    };
    this.weighted = weighted;
}
static int checkStyle (int style) {
    int mask = SWT.BORDER | SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT | SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT;
    return style & mask;
}
Sash createSash() {
    Sash sash = new Sash(this, sashStyle);
    sash.setBackground(background);
    sash.setForeground(foreground);
    sash.setToolTipText(getToolTipText());
    sash.addListener(SWT.Selection, sashListener);
    return sash;
}

@Override
public int getOrientation() {
    //checkWidget();
    return (sashStyle & SWT.VERTICAL) != 0 ? SWT.HORIZONTAL : SWT.VERTICAL;
}
/**
 * Returns the width of the sashes when the controls in the SashForm are 
 * laid out.
 * 
 * @return the width of the sashes
 * 
 * @exception SWTException <ul>
 *    <li>ERROR_WIDGET_DISPOSED - if the receiver has been disposed</li>
 *    <li>ERROR_THREAD_INVALID_ACCESS - if not called from the thread that created the receiver</li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @since 3.4
 */
public int getSashWidth() {
    checkWidget();
    return SASH_WIDTH;
}
@Override
public int getStyle() {
    int style = super.getStyle();
    style |= getOrientation() == SWT.VERTICAL ? SWT.VERTICAL : SWT.HORIZONTAL;
    if ((sashStyle & SWT.SMOOTH) != 0) style |= SWT.SMOOTH;
    return style;
}
/**
 * Answer the control that currently is maximized in the SashForm.  
 * This value may be null.
 * 
 * @return the control that currently is maximized or null
 */
public Control getMaximizedControl(){
    //checkWidget();
    return this.maxControl;
}

public int[] getWeights() {
    checkWidget();
    Control[] cArray = getControls(false);
    int[] ratios = new int[cArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
        Object data = cArray[i].getLayoutData();
        if (data != null && data instanceof SashFormData) {
            ratios[i] = (int)(((SashFormData)data).weight * 1000 >> 16);
        } else {
            ratios[i] = 200;
        }
    }
    return ratios;
}
Control[] getControls(boolean onlyVisible) {
    Control[] children = getChildren();
    Control[] result = new Control[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (children[i] instanceof Sash) continue;
        if (onlyVisible && !children[i].getVisible()) continue;

        Control[] newResult = new Control[result.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(result, 0, newResult, 0, result.length);
        newResult[result.length] = children[i];
        result = newResult;
    }
    return result;
}
boolean getWeighted() {
    return weighted;
}
void onDragSash(Event event) {
    Sash sash = (Sash)event.widget;
    int sashIndex = -1;
    for (int i= 0; i < sashes.length; i++) {
        if (sashes[i] == sash) {
            sashIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (sashIndex == -1) return;

    Control c1 = controls[sashIndex];
    Control c2 = controls[sashIndex + 1];
    Rectangle b1 = c1.getBounds();
    Rectangle b2 = c2.getBounds();

    Rectangle sashBounds = sash.getBounds();
    Rectangle area = getClientArea();
    boolean correction = false;
    if (getOrientation() == SWT.HORIZONTAL) {
        correction = b1.width < DRAG_MINIMUM || b2.width < DRAG_MINIMUM;
        int totalWidth = b2.x + b2.width - b1.x; 
        int shift = event.x - sashBounds.x;
        b1.width += shift;
        b2.x += shift;
        b2.width -= shift;
        if (b1.width < DRAG_MINIMUM) {
            b1.width = DRAG_MINIMUM;
            b2.x = b1.x + b1.width + sashBounds.width;
            b2.width = totalWidth - b2.x;
            event.x = b1.x + b1.width;
            event.doit = false;
        }
        if (b2.width < DRAG_MINIMUM) {
            b1.width = totalWidth - DRAG_MINIMUM - sashBounds.width;
            b2.x = b1.x + b1.width + sashBounds.width;
            b2.width = DRAG_MINIMUM;
            event.x = b1.x + b1.width;
            event.doit = false;
        }
        Object data1 = c1.getLayoutData();
        if (data1 == null || !(data1 instanceof SashFormData)) {
            data1 = new SashFormData();
            c1.setLayoutData(data1);
        }
        Object data2 = c2.getLayoutData();
        if (data2 == null || !(data2 instanceof SashFormData)) {
            data2 = new SashFormData();
            c2.setLayoutData(data2);
        }
        ((SashFormData)data1).weight = (((long)b1.width << 16) + area.width - 1) / area.width;
        ((SashFormData)data1).length = b1.width;
        ((SashFormData)data2).weight = (((long)b2.width << 16) + area.width - 1) / area.width;
        ((SashFormData)data2).length = b2.width;
    } else {
        correction = b1.height < DRAG_MINIMUM || b2.height < DRAG_MINIMUM;
        int totalHeight = b2.y + b2.height - b1.y;
        int shift = event.y - sashBounds.y;
        b1.height += shift;
        b2.y += shift;
        b2.height -= shift;
        if (b1.height < DRAG_MINIMUM) {
            b1.height = DRAG_MINIMUM;
            b2.y = b1.y + b1.height + sashBounds.height;
            b2.height = totalHeight - b2.y;
            event.y = b1.y + b1.height;
            event.doit = false;
        }
        if (b2.height < DRAG_MINIMUM) {
            b1.height = totalHeight - DRAG_MINIMUM - sashBounds.height;
            b2.y = b1.y + b1.height + sashBounds.height;
            b2.height = DRAG_MINIMUM;
            event.y = b1.y + b1.height;
            event.doit = false;
        }
        Object data1 = c1.getLayoutData();
        if (data1 == null || !(data1 instanceof SashFormData)) {
            data1 = new SashFormData();
            c1.setLayoutData(data1);
        }
        Object data2 = c2.getLayoutData();
        if (data2 == null || !(data2 instanceof SashFormData)) {
            data2 = new SashFormData();
            c2.setLayoutData(data2);
        }
        ((SashFormData)data1).weight = (((long)b1.height << 16) + area.height - 1) / area.height;
        ((SashFormData)data2).weight = (((long)b2.height << 16) + area.height - 1) / area.height;
    }
    if (correction || (event.doit && event.detail != SWT.DRAG)) {
        c1.setBounds(b1);
        sash.setBounds(event.x, event.y, event.width, event.height);
        c2.setBounds(b2);
    }
}

@Override
public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    checkWidget();
    if (orientation == SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT || orientation == SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT) {
        super.setOrientation(orientation);
        return;
    }
    if (getOrientation() == orientation) return;
    if (orientation != SWT.HORIZONTAL && orientation != SWT.VERTICAL) {
        SWT.error(SWT.ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
    }
    sashStyle &= ~(SWT.HORIZONTAL | SWT.VERTICAL);
    sashStyle |= orientation == SWT.VERTICAL ? SWT.HORIZONTAL : SWT.VERTICAL;
    for (int i = 0; i < sashes.length; i++) {
        sashes[i].dispose();
        sashes[i] = createSash();
    }
    layout(false);
}
@Override
public void setBackground (Color color) {
    super.setBackground(color);
    background = color;
    for (int i = 0; i < sashes.length; i++) {
        sashes[i].setBackground(background);
    }
}
@Override
public void setForeground (Color color) {
    super.setForeground(color);
    foreground = color;
    for (int i = 0; i < sashes.length; i++) {
        sashes[i].setForeground(foreground);
    }
}

@Override
public void setLayout (Layout layout) {
    checkWidget();
    return;
}

public void setMaximizedControl(Control control){
    checkWidget();
    if (control == null) {
        if (maxControl != null) {
            this.maxControl = null;
            layout(false);
            for (int i= 0; i < sashes.length; i++){
                sashes[i].setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    for (int i= 0; i < sashes.length; i++){
        sashes[i].setVisible(false);
    }
    maxControl = control;
    layout(false);
}

public void setSashWidth(int width) {
    checkWidget();
    if (SASH_WIDTH == width) return;
    SASH_WIDTH = width;
    layout(false);
}
@Override
public void setToolTipText(String string) {
    super.setToolTipText(string);
    for (int i = 0; i < sashes.length; i++) {
        sashes[i].setToolTipText(string);
    }
}

public void setWeights(int[] weights) {
    checkWidget();
    Control[] cArray = getControls(false);
    if (weights == null || weights.length != cArray.length) {
        SWT.error(SWT.ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
    }

    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
        if (weights[i] < 0) {
            SWT.error(SWT.ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
        }
        total += weights[i];
    }
    if (total == 0) {
        SWT.error(SWT.ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
        Object data = cArray[i].getLayoutData();
        if (data == null || !(data instanceof SashFormData)) {
            data = new SashFormData();
            cArray[i].setLayoutData(data);
        }
        ((SashFormData)data).weight = (((long)weights[i] << 16) + total - 1) / total;
    }

    layout(false);
}

public void setLengths(int[] lengths) {
    checkWidget();
    Control[] cArray = getControls(false);
    if (lengths == null || lengths.length != cArray.length) {
        SWT.error(SWT.ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
    }

    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lengths.length; i++) {
        if (lengths[i] < 0) {
            SWT.error(SWT.ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
        }
        total += lengths[i];
    }
    if (total == 0) {
        SWT.error(SWT.ERROR_INVALID_ARGUMENT);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
        Object data = cArray[i].getLayoutData();
        if (data == null || !(data instanceof SashFormData)) {
            data = new SashFormData();
            cArray[i].setLayoutData(data);
        }
        ((SashFormData)data).length = lengths[i];
    }

    layout(false);
}
}
```

SashFormData.java:

```
class SashFormData {

    long weight;
    int length;

String getName () {
    String string = getClass ().getName ();
    int index = string.lastIndexOf ('.');
    if (index == -1) return string;
    return string.substring (index + 1, string.length ());
}

@Override
public String toString () {
    return getName()+" {length="+length+", weight="+weight+"}"; //$NON-NLS-2$
}
}
```

SashFormLayout.java:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

class SashFormLayout extends Layout {
    @Override
    protected Point computeSize(Composite composite, int wHint, int hHint, boolean flushCache) {
        SashForm sashForm = (SashForm)composite;
        Control[] cArray = sashForm.getControls(true);
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        if (cArray.length == 0) {       
            if (wHint != SWT.DEFAULT) width = wHint;
            if (hHint != SWT.DEFAULT) height = hHint;
            return new Point(width, height);
        }
        // determine control sizes
        boolean vertical = sashForm.getOrientation() == SWT.VERTICAL;

        if (sashForm.getWeighted()) {
            int maxIndex = 0;
            int maxValue = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
                if (vertical) {
                    Point size = cArray[i].computeSize(wHint, SWT.DEFAULT, flushCache);
                    if (size.y > maxValue) {
                        maxIndex = i;
                        maxValue = size.y;
                    }
                    width = Math.max(width, size.x);
                } else {
                    Point size = cArray[i].computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, hHint, flushCache);
                    if (size.x > maxValue) {
                        maxIndex = i;
                        maxValue = size.x;
                    }
                    height = Math.max(height, size.y);
                }
            }
            // get the ratios
            long[] ratios = new long[cArray.length];
            long total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
                Object data = cArray[i].getLayoutData();
                if (data != null && data instanceof SashFormData) {
                    ratios[i] = ((SashFormData)data).weight;
                } else {
                    data = new SashFormData();
                    cArray[i].setLayoutData(data);
                    ((SashFormData)data).weight = ratios[i] = ((200 << 16) + 999) / 1000;

                }
                total += ratios[i];
            }
            if (ratios[maxIndex] > 0) {
                int sashwidth = sashForm.sashes.length > 0 ? sashForm.SASH_WIDTH + sashForm.sashes [0].getBorderWidth() * 2 : sashForm.SASH_WIDTH;
                if (vertical) {
                    height += (int)(total * maxValue / ratios[maxIndex]) + (cArray.length - 1) * sashwidth;
                } else {
                    width += (int)(total * maxValue / ratios[maxIndex]) + (cArray.length - 1) * sashwidth;
                }
            }
        } else {
            int maxIndex = 0;
            int maxValue = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
                if (vertical) {
                    Point size = cArray[i].computeSize(wHint, SWT.DEFAULT, flushCache);
                    if (size.y > maxValue) {
                        maxIndex = i;
                        maxValue = size.y;
                    }
                    width = Math.max(width, size.x);
                } else {
                    Point size = cArray[i].computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, hHint, flushCache);
                    if (size.x > maxValue) {
                        maxIndex = i;
                        maxValue = size.x;
                    }
                    height = Math.max(height, size.y);
                }
            }
            // get the lengths
            int[] lengths = new int[cArray.length];
            long total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++) {
                Object data = cArray[i].getLayoutData();
                if (data != null && data instanceof SashFormData) {
                    lengths[i] = ((SashFormData)data).length;
                } else {
                    data = new SashFormData();
                    cArray[i].setLayoutData(data);
                    ((SashFormData)data).length = sashForm.getOrientation() == SWT.HORIZONTAL ? cArray[i].getSize().x : cArray[i].getSize().y;
                }
                total += lengths[i];
            }
            if (lengths[maxIndex] > 0) {
                int sashwidth = sashForm.sashes.length > 0 ? sashForm.SASH_WIDTH + sashForm.sashes [0].getBorderWidth() * 2 : sashForm.SASH_WIDTH;
                if (vertical) {
                    height += total + (cArray.length - 1) * sashwidth;
                } else {
                    width +=  total + (cArray.length - 1) * sashwidth;
                }
            }
        }
        width += sashForm.getBorderWidth()*2;
        height += sashForm.getBorderWidth()*2;
        if (wHint != SWT.DEFAULT) width = wHint;
        if (hHint != SWT.DEFAULT) height = hHint;
        return new Point(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean flushCache(Control control) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void layout(Composite composite, boolean flushCache) {
        SashForm sashForm = (SashForm)composite;
        Rectangle area = sashForm.getClientArea();
        if (area.width <= 1 || area.height <= 1) return;

        Control[] newControls = sashForm.getControls(true);
        if (sashForm.controls.length == 0 && newControls.length == 0) return;
        sashForm.controls = newControls;

        Control[] controls = sashForm.controls;

        if (sashForm.maxControl != null && !sashForm.maxControl.isDisposed()) {
            for (int i= 0; i < controls.length; i++){
                if (controls[i] != sashForm.maxControl) {
                    controls[i].setBounds(-200, -200, 0, 0);
                } else {
                    controls[i].setBounds(area);
                }
            }
            return;
        }

        // keep just the right number of sashes
        if (sashForm.sashes.length < controls.length - 1) {
            Sash[] newSashes = new Sash[controls.length - 1];
            System.arraycopy(sashForm.sashes, 0, newSashes, 0, sashForm.sashes.length);
            for (int i = sashForm.sashes.length; i < newSashes.length; i++) {
                newSashes[i] = sashForm.createSash();
            }
            sashForm.sashes = newSashes;
        }
        if (sashForm.sashes.length > controls.length - 1) {
            if (controls.length == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < sashForm.sashes.length; i++) {
                    sashForm.sashes[i].dispose();
                }
                sashForm.sashes = new Sash[0];
            } else {
                Sash[] newSashes = new Sash[controls.length - 1];
                System.arraycopy(sashForm.sashes, 0, newSashes, 0, newSashes.length);
                for (int i = controls.length - 1; i < sashForm.sashes.length; i++) {
                    sashForm.sashes[i].dispose();
                }
                sashForm.sashes = newSashes;
            }
        }
        if (controls.length == 0) return;
        Sash[] sashes = sashForm.sashes;

        if (sashForm.getWeighted()) {
            // get the ratios
            long[] ratios = new long[controls.length];
            long total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
                Object data = controls[i].getLayoutData();
                if (data != null && data instanceof SashFormData) {
                    ratios[i] = ((SashFormData)data).weight;
                } else {
                    data = new SashFormData();
                    controls[i].setLayoutData(data);
                    ((SashFormData)data).weight = ratios[i] = ((200 << 16) + 999) / 1000;

                }
                total += ratios[i];
            }
            int sashwidth = sashes.length > 0 ? sashForm.SASH_WIDTH + sashes [0].getBorderWidth() * 2 : sashForm.SASH_WIDTH;
            if (sashForm.getOrientation() == SWT.HORIZONTAL) {
                int width = (int)(ratios[0] * (area.width - sashes.length * sashwidth) / total);
                int x = area.x;
                controls[0].setBounds(x, area.y, width, area.height);
                x += width;
                for (int i = 1; i < controls.length - 1; i++) {
                    sashes[i - 1].setBounds(x, area.y, sashwidth, area.height);
                    x += sashwidth;
                    width = (int)(ratios[i] * (area.width - sashes.length * sashwidth) / total);
                    controls[i].setBounds(x, area.y, width, area.height);
                    x += width;
                }
                if (controls.length > 1) {
                    sashes[sashes.length - 1].setBounds(x, area.y, sashwidth, area.height);
                    x += sashwidth;
                    width = area.width - x;
                    controls[controls.length - 1].setBounds(x, area.y, width, area.height);
                }
            } else {
                int height = (int)(ratios[0] * (area.height - sashes.length * sashwidth) / total);
                int y = area.y;
                controls[0].setBounds(area.x, y, area.width, height);
                y += height;
                for (int i = 1; i < controls.length - 1; i++) {
                    sashes[i - 1].setBounds(area.x, y, area.width, sashwidth);
                    y += sashwidth;
                    height = (int)(ratios[i] * (area.height - sashes.length * sashwidth) / total);
                    controls[i].setBounds(area.x, y, area.width, height);
                    y += height;
                }
                if (controls.length > 1) {
                    sashes[sashes.length - 1].setBounds(area.x, y, area.width, sashwidth);
                    y += sashwidth;
                    height = area.height - y;
                    controls[controls.length - 1].setBounds(area.x, y, area.width, height);
                }

            } 
        } else {
            // get the lengths
            int[] lengths = new int[controls.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < controls.length; i++) {
                Object data = controls[i].getLayoutData();
                if (data != null && data instanceof SashFormData) {
                    lengths[i] = ((SashFormData)data).length;
                } else {
                    data = new SashFormData();
                    controls[i].setLayoutData(data);
                    ((SashFormData)data).length = sashForm.getOrientation() == SWT.HORIZONTAL ? controls[i].getSize().x : controls[i].getSize().y;
                }
            }
            int sashwidth = sashes.length > 0 ? sashForm.SASH_WIDTH + sashes [0].getBorderWidth() * 2 : sashForm.SASH_WIDTH;
            if (sashForm.getOrientation() == SWT.HORIZONTAL) {
                int width = lengths[0];
                int x = area.x;
                controls[0].setBounds(x, area.y, width, area.height);
                x += width;
                for (int i = 1; i < controls.length - 1; i++) {
                    sashes[i - 1].setBounds(x, area.y, sashwidth, area.height);
                    x += sashwidth;
                    width = lengths[i];
                    controls[i].setBounds(x, area.y, width, area.height);
                    x += width;
                }
                if (controls.length > 1) {
                    sashes[sashes.length - 1].setBounds(x, area.y, sashwidth, area.height);
                    x += sashwidth;
                    width = area.width - x;
                    controls[controls.length - 1].setBounds(x, area.y, width, area.height);
                }
            } else {
                int height = lengths[0];
                int y = area.y;
                controls[0].setBounds(area.x, y, area.width, height);
                y += height;
                for (int i = 1; i < controls.length - 1; i++) {
                    sashes[i - 1].setBounds(area.x, y, area.width, sashwidth);
                    y += sashwidth;
                    height = lengths[i];
                    controls[i].setBounds(area.x, y, area.width, height);
                    y += height;
                }
                if (controls.length > 1) {
                    sashes[sashes.length - 1].setBounds(area.x, y, area.width, sashwidth);
                    y += sashwidth;
                    height = area.height - y;
                    controls[controls.length - 1].setBounds(area.x, y, area.width, height);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```