# How to set custom width of children within sashform

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I have to set the width of the sash form based on the length of the longest string of the children within the sash form. My sash form has 4 sections. So I have to consider the length of all strings from all these sections so as to set the width of the sash form.
For ex : Sashform A has 2 sections. Sec A has 3 children (abc,xd, asdfg) and Sec B has 2 children (assdfggj, ath). I want to set the width of the sash form based on the longest string, ie assdfggj. How can I set it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Constant Width SashForm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227086/constant-width-sashform)

Comment: No Esmaeli. Tried this code. Did not work.

Comment: SashForm is based on weights, not absolute values so you would have to do something like in the link. Otherwise you could try to craft something of your own using `Sash` controls.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.